# jest for testing describe is not a function

Tags: redux, jestjs

I have made an app using react and redux, I have some components plus their containers and also an action and a reducer.

I am writing a test for one of my containers using enzyme, chai and jest,

when I try to run my test it gives the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: jest_1.describe is not a function
```

here is my test file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import * as Sinon from "sinon";
import MinPriceContainer from "../../src/containers/SearchForm/containers/MinPriceContainer";
import MaxPriceContainer from "../../src/containers/SearchForm/containers/MaxPriceContainer";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { it, before, describe } from 'jest';

describe('<MinValueInput />', () => {

    let minValueInput;
    beforeEach(() => {
        minValueInput = shallow(<MinPriceContainer />);
    })

//    it('renders component correctly', () => {
//        expect(tabs.find('.MinPriceComponent').exists()).toBe(true);
//    });

    it('cannot have a non numeric value', () => {
        minValueInput = shallow(<MinPriceContainer minimumPriceSelected="i am a string not a number" />);
        expect(minValueInput.find('.error').text()).equal("You cannot use a non numeric value");
    });

    it('cannot have a value less thn zero', () => {
        minValueInput = shallow(<MinPriceContainer minimumPriceSelected={-20} />);
        expect(minValueInput.find('.error').text()).equal("value cannot be less than zero");
    });

    it('it can not have a value greater than maxValue', () => {
        minValueInput = shallow(<MinPriceContainer minimumPriceSelected={99} maximumPriceSelected={80}/>);
        expect(minValueInput.find('.error').text()).equal("value cannot be greater than price");
    });
});
```

how can I fix this, is this related to my importS?
is the test written correctly?

the component that I am testing has a number value called minPrice and it can not be negative and also it should not be more than another component that is called maxPrice, also it should only accepts numbers!

Answer (score 3):

I take it you're using ts-jest?

replace

`import { it, before, describe } from 'jest';`

with

`import 'jest';`

Comment: Hey @Fusselwurm, this worked for me! But how do you suggest I get rid of the TS errors since now it says `describe is not defined`. The tests are passing fine though